# how do I find in which file the css is written?

Tags: css, wordpress

Headers for my site are showing the incorrect font. I can't figure out where the css is coming from. It is only happening on one specific page (/national) on the site.
when I do inspect element I see: xxx.com/national:766

```
   h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {  font-family: "jaf-facitweb", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif!important;}
```

what does : number mean? 
Where is the css for this written? How can I change it? 
My site is live at http://testsitemg.com/meor-yale/national/ you can this this issue for all the h3 headers. 
I want the font to show

```
h3 {  font-family: Georgia, serif;}
```

as it is set in the theme settings.

Comment: Remove the !important at the end the first line.

Comment: xxx.com/national:766 means it's located directly in the html in a `<style></style>` tag

Comment: thanks, that helped me find it. I viewed the page source and then located where the <style> tag was coming from

Answer (score 1):

For find in which css file is signed a property you can open you web page win firebug and or other web page analisys tools and inspect the HTML, in the lower window when you touch an element the right side show the css property and files where they came from